Open electron devtools docked as default
I'm creating an application with Electron-Vite and could not find any way to set the default behavior of the devtools when opening to be docked on the right like on chorme. When i manually switch it in options inside the devtools but close it or run the application again, it defaults back to opening detached and not docked as i previously changed. Does any one has a solution for this?
expected
reality

using contents.openDevTools([options]) you can change the default location of your dev tools.
If you want the dev tools to open on the right side add :
  win.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'right' })


It only opens the devtool on that mode when the application starts, if you close it a re-open it, the devtools will be detached again.

can you include code ?
